# Database Design: How should I store user's news preferences in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to implement a personalized news aggregator. I have to save user's preferred news sources in db. Should I store all the news sources liked by a user as JSON string and then decode it after retrieving?

`feeds | user`

or have individual column for each news source(no of news sources would be around 200)?

```
feed_name1 | feed_name2 | .....  | user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a many-to-many situation. A solution that used a person table, a newsfeed table, and a person_newsfeed table might be appropriate.  There are lots of articles on line about this and any good database theory book (or Something like Oracle: The Complete Reference) should cover this in detail.

This article is a pretty good (but very short) summary:
http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_xtox/

Oracle8 The Complete Reference covers this around page 35 with the worker, skill, workerskills example during their discussion of third normal form.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this. I've been doing it wrong all this time!